# How do I improve the UI of a webpage that expands as you use it?

Tags: gui-design, lists

I have a [website](https://www.translationiteration.com) that constantly gets bigger and bigger as a user uses it. It is not yet complete, although I believe it is time for a better UI. So, how do I make it so the user feels more welcome. Currently it's a blue and orange, with round buttons and text boxes, but I was thinking of making changing it to make the textboxes and buttons rectangular with thick, neon-light-blue borders and a black background, somewhat similar to the Zorin OS linux distrobution. Is it smart to use a darker theme with a dynamic page, or should I keep it the same?

Comment: This is a pretty interesting website. Perhaps the focus shouldn't be on the UI but the UX...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dark theme will make your page stand out, whether in a good way or not is down to the specific implementation, but most pages default to a light theme.

The current blue-orange palette is very high contrast and might be jarring for users, especially given the subject matter. Compared to other language based sites (eg, [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/)), which generally consist of a light theme focusing on a single accent color, your site stands out.

Using a dark theme may not be a bad idea overall if it suits the aesthetic you want for the site, but moving away from two colors would help calm the site down at least.

Comment: I didn't even consider how it competes vs. normal dictionary sites, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The current version was bit difficult for me as a user to follow. Maybe if you created cards (like decks of material design) that are placed next to each other, it would be easier to follow through. Also, keeping a light theme is definitely the preferred choice. It will be less stressful to the eyes and is found to have higher engagement than a dark theme such as the one you currently have.